# How to load AMD modules from external file using webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, module, require, amd

Working on a project I came across the case where I need to load a third party file written as AMD modules using a script tag: `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.host.com/external.js"></script>`.

The file contains multiple modules which the example code uses like:

```
require(['src/module/MyObject'], (myObject) => {
 // Use myObject
});
```

The example includes RequireJS as a script tag to enable this syntax.
Now...my project is a React app with Webpack in which I would like to access 'myObject' somewhere in a component but I cannot seem to get this to work.

Using just the require() syntax fails because Webpack tries to add the code to the bundle. I tried the '**non_webpack_require**' alternative, keeping the RequireJS script tag but this seems to add all sorts of conflicts elsewhere in the code (undefined stuff all over the place). I also tried fiddling with the webpack 'External' property but can't seem to get this to work as expected either. The latter seems the way to go but I end up with 'src/module/MyObject' is undefined errors.

Any help appreciated.

**Edit**: 
As requested, the related part of my webpack.config:

```
{
  entry: './src/index.tsx',

  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: `js/[name].[contenthash].bundle.js`,
    chunkFilename: 'js/[name].[contenthash].js',
  },

  resolve: {
    // Add '.ts' and '.tsx' as resolvable extensions.
    extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.json'],
    plugins: [
      new TsconfigPathsPlugin(),
    ],
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
        },
        exclude: [/node_modules/],
      },
    ],
  },
}
```

Comment: If you include the library in HTML, it has nothing to do with Webpack. Check in your browser's devconsole after loading the app if `myObject` is a global variable.

Comment: Yeah, so I could just download the file and include it in my bundle. But still no clue on how to do this. Also, there does not seem to be a global object.And also...I do not want to have to include the RequireJS library in a script tag because it breaks other things

Comment: You don't need RequireJS if you include it locally using Webpack, as Webpack should support that. What library are you using? I can have a look

Comment: This is the file: https://cdn.bitmovin.com/player/cast/8.1.0/bitmovinplayer-remotereceiver.js

Comment: Can you post related part of you Webpack configuration too?

Comment: @kkkkkkk not sure if it helps but I added it to the post.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using the wrong example.

`RequireJS` is a different old modules resolver. usually, you should not have `webpack` as well `Requirejs` within the same project. there are some edge cases, but this is not one of them.

I was looking a little bit in that lib you gave and they do have es6 module packages, you should look at the following example :

https://github.com/bitmovin/bitmovin-player-web-samples/tree/master/webpack-demo

This will be the best way to go.

If you still for some reason want to use their CDN, Then the right one for you is :

https://cdn.bitmovin.com/player/web/8/bitmovinplayer.js

see full demos repo here (they have react as well)

https://github.com/bitmovin/bitmovin-player-web-samples

Comment: Hi @jony89. Thank for the deepdive! Much appreciated. The thing is I want to use their Chromecast library (not only the player), which is currently only available in the format I prodvided. I know the differences between RequireJS and Webpack but unfortunately it's just how it is at the moment.